# What does the word robo means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was looking at another StackExchange site and saw this phrase:

> Although it was ultimately accepted, the reviewers who accepted it
>   look more like **robo-reviewers** than those who rejected it.

When I tried to search on a search-engine for the meaning it almost always referenced to a Spanish term that apparently means to steal / or to be stolen from. (depending on the pronunciation).

But I cannot see this meaning to be related at all with this phrase that I posted.

Source of the post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254122/is-this-edit-correct-or-does-it-change-too-much-of-the-question?cb=1

Comment: You would have done much better to search for "robo-reviewer" and "roboreviewer" on the site where you saw the post. The term is in common use on meta (spelled both ways) and it is one of many meta-specific slang/jargon phrases. Knowing what "gimme teh codez" means in a dictionary won't help you know what it means on meta.

Comment: @ RegDwigнt♦, the link you posted doesn't really explain why it's related as @outis nihil did.

Comment: There's an argument to be made that this should be in ELL or some other site, though, or that (as it is tagged) it can be answered with commonly-available references. @RegDwigнt has a much higher reputation than I do; he's more familiar with the way things are done here than I am.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun: why it's related to what? That it's related to *robot* is explained there alright. (Though it's pretty transparent, what with robocops and robodogs and robofish and all.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is derived from *robot*, meaning *an automaton*, which itself derives from the play *R. U. R.* In this case, *robo* means *automated*, and conveys a tone of disapproval.

Answer (score 2):

[Etymology robot](https://www.google.ie/search?q=etymology%20robot&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=GPlsU6qTMITQygOi9oHgBg)
from Czech, from robota ‘forced labour’. The term was coined in K. Čapek's play R.U.R. ‘Rossum's Universal Robots’ (1920).

Same link: a person who behaves in a mechanical or unemotional manner.

Comment: Etymology:  Russian _работа_ /rabóta/, from Proto-Slavic root **orbota* 'hard work, slavery', derived from P-S **orbь* 'slave'. Cognate with German _Arbeit._

Comment: But today, *робота* and its cognates no longer have any connotation of slavery -- they're just the ordinary word for "work".